# Some verification of localization of categories

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

I'm doing some verifation of a lemma about localization of categories. It is in Gelfand-Manin, "Method of Homological Algebra", Lemma 2.2.8.
Before the lemma, it defined the so-called localizing class of morphism, satisfying L1), L2) and L3) as follows:
[image]

[image]

In the proof of the lemma
[image]
[image]

the authors state that the symmetry is obvious, while one needs L3) to get the transitivity.

However, I did some verification, that symmetry is not obvious but transitivity is clear. For transitivity, it is simply find a $$Z'''$$ (using L2)) at the top of the following diagram
[image]
and the commutativity is OK. But to prove the symmetry, one has the diagram like (III.10), where $h:X'''\to X''$ is not in $S$, so one needs to find $Z\to X'''$ and $Z'\to X''$ using L2) s.t. $Z'\to X''$ is in $S$, then use L3) to find $Z\to Z'$ cancelling $t:X''\to X$. This is the trick that the author used in proving transitivity.

So my questions are: Which proof is correct? Why did they use L3) in proving transitivity?

Comment: Typically one requires that the class $S$ have the 2-out-of-3 property (if any two of $f$, $g$, or $g \circ f$ are in $S$, then all three are) , which is a strengthening of the first condition. In that case, the morphism $h$ in the diagram (III.10) is forced to be in $S$ and therefore symmetry is indeed "obvious".

Comment: @ZhenLin For homotopical cats and practically, yes, we have 2-out-of-3. But here it is not really needed and general definition does not imply it. Only use the definition I don't really think it is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to bring up this question, but someone told me how to do this, while he didn't really want to answer this question. I'm posting it here, in case this would help someone else.

The problem comes from the definition of being equivalent. Gelfand-Manin doesn't really give it correctly - well, at least not clear. In diagram III.10, $s,t$ and $sr$ are in $U$ while $r$ might not be. The roof the book refers should be the large roof. And by this definition, all proofs provided by the textbook make sense.